# How to adjust width of relative layouts in percent?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, percentage, android-relativelayout

How can I adjust the width of my 2 Relative Layouts correctly, so that the one to the left takes **0.25** of screen space and the one to the right takes **0.75**? Inside the second relative layout there's a table layout with 3 columns, each of them should take **1/3** of table's size.

Here's what I've tried with AXML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonsLeft"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
                android:text="@string/btnBack"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/myBtnWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/myBtnHeight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/myBtnMargin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/myBtnMargin" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
                android:text="@string/btnStart"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/myBtnWidth"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/myBtnHeight"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/myBtnMargin"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/myBtnMargin" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.75">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableRight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1">
                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Text1"
                        android:padding="10sp"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/myTextSizeColHeader"
                        android:text="@string/bin"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/myColWidthBin"
                        android:gravity="left" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Text2"
                        android:padding="10sp"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/myTextSizeColHeader"
                        android:text="@string/item_customer"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/myColWidthItemCust"
                        android:gravity="center" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Text4"
                        android:padding="10sp"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/myTextSizeColHeader"
                        android:text="@string/nominal_actualQty"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/myColWidthActNomQty"
                        android:gravity="right" />
                </TableRow>
                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/whseActivHeadersList" />
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/notificationsNextorder"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `weightSum` to parent linear layout. 
Check this answer

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3">

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there a difference between setting the weightSum to 1 and then 0.25 and 0.75 for the two relative layouts and your variant? By the way, it produces better result now, but still it doesn't answer how to make each column 1/3 of the table's size.

Comment: No. you can use weight sum as 1 and weight 0.25 and 0.75. and use this same method to adjust table view

Comment: Thanks!! I used the same method for the nested linear layout. I'll update my question.